# What is haslayout?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I've read some article on it but didn't get what is actually. can anyone on SO explain me.

Is it only related to IE6 only?

What does `zoom:1`?

Is `layout` is a IE only TAG?

**Edit:**

I found this info very informative for me

> Because Internet Explorer is so old
>   (as it was one of the first browsers
>   available), it hasn’t had the luxury
>   of starting anew as current browser
>   do. So as time went by, Microsoft
>   began adapting new engines to make use
>   of CSS. Seems fine… However, CSS
>   changes the fundamental assumption
>   that Internet Explorer’s engine is
>   based on – that anything significant
>   is a rectangle that contains all its
>   content.
>
> So to deal with the new standards of
>   CSS, Microsoft decided to fix their
>   ancient engine by implementing the
>   hasLayout property, instead of
>   rebuilding IE. Every element in
>   Internet Explorer now has a hasLayout
>   property. Depending on the element, it
>   is set to either true or false by
>   default. If hasLayout is set to true –
>   the element is an independent box that
>   is responsible for rendering itself.
>   If false – then the element relies on
>   a parent element that has hasLayout
>   set to true to render it. This is
>   where a majority of IE bugs come to
>   life.

source: http://bytesizecss.com/blog/post/fix-haslayout-with-one-line-of-css

I found one more discussion here also : http://www.molly.com/2007/03/30/back-to-work-someone-please-clearly-articulate-haslayout/

Comment: Of course the truth is Microsoft flat out screwed up when they were interpreting the specification and didn't implement the box model correctly making the lives of us web developers miserable to this day.

Comment: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: I think that's the article he referred to which he didn't understand.

Comment: .. seeing as how it's the most referenced article for hasLayout in existence I assumed, at least

Comment: From where i can found accurate list of elements . which has layout and which has not.?

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481%28VS.85%29.aspx, http://haslayout.net/haslayout, http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/haslayout.html, http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: can i add *{height:1%} in IE 6 only css to solve this problem forever?

Comment: "which if triggered, causes the element to be rendered in a certain way ( which can be unexpected, random, can be a godsend or can be hell )."

Comment: It's common to use zoom for temporary universal assignment, height would not be wise.

Comment: Jesus christ, this is a fully loaded friggin' question.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162625/why-does-internet-explorer-need-the-haslayout-flag

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a **non-standard** property on an HTML element which is only supported by IE7 and lower ( IE8 compatability mode too ), which if triggered, causes the element to be rendered in a certain way ( which can be unexpected, random, can be a godsend or can be hell ).

Classic example is giving layout to an element so it can clear floats.

```
#wrapper { zoom:1; }
```

The element will now contain floats. Any of these properties and value other than auto/normal will trigger the layout property.

```
* display: inline-block
* height: (any value except auto)
* float: (left or right)
* position: absolute
* width: (any value except auto)
* writing-mode: tb-rl
* zoom: (any value except normal)
```

Please have a thorough read @ http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

Comment: layout means width and height?

Comment: ok it means haslayout is related to windows version of IE6 and 7. then what about IE8 and IE8's compatibility mode?

Comment: but zoom:1 is not valid css property

Comment: please explaing this part "specific value that's not auto/normal will trigger layout." What do you means of specific value and trigger layout?

Comment: 1. you give an element layout by setting any of the properties listed ( those aren't all the possible ones, read http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout for reference )
2. IE8's compatability mimics IE7 therefore `hasLayout` is on the compatability mode.
3. Right

Comment: 4. For example width:auto doesnt trigger but width:1px would.

Comment: ok i got it from (any value except auto) u mean any value in px , em, % . but what is height 1%

Comment: Setting any of those values on the element will trigger IE's "layout" behavior.  Some other rules won't behave properly in IE unless it this has been triggered.  `zoom: 1` is commonly used precisely because it's not a valid CSS property, thus other browsers will ignore it.

Comment: "height: (any value except auto)" - this means any value other than auto.

Comment: "Trigger layout" means IE only "layout" property will be applied. am i right?

Comment: "Trigger layout" means it turns the hasLayout property on.

Comment: u mean "haslayout" is IE specfic CSS property and we need to turn it on in specfic condition whenever we need?

Comment: We've already established that it's IE specific, let's forget about other browsers. Whenever you assign a property such as the ones specified, it turns it on whether you want to or not, sometimes in order to fix bugs you have to manually turn it on by specifying any of the properties and a specific value, so it's rendered differently.

Comment: but my question is what is actually ""haslayout" is it's a CSS property, a html tag or attributes, a javascript property?

for example zoom:1  and scroll bar css are a IE specific property.

Comment: It's a property in the DOM/JS of IE. Certain combinations of css applied to the element set the value to be true/1.

Comment: haslayout is related to IE 6 and 7 both but mostly error comes in IE6 only. Why not in IE 7?

Comment: With version 7, IE started to pay more attention to matching CSS specs.  It's still not perfect, and IE8 cleans it up even more, but IE7 was much better at it than IE6.

Comment: width: 100% didn't help me, and neither did zoom: 1.  But float: left fixed my weird IE7 placement issue. Thanks!