# Collapsing margins/paddings at the bottom of blockquote

Tags: html, css

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svLzhb1y/) with live demo.

I want to make padding at top and at bottom of the blockquote to be equal (0.5em to be precise).

[image]

At first look, basic and trivial task, but I faced with a problem - collapsing margins/paddings (if I understand it right) at the bottom of blockquote.

I found some workarounds (like adding a 1px border or padding), but it surely very dirty.

So, the question: Is there a good way to make padding at top and at bottom of the blockquotes to be equal, like shown in the image?

```
<style>
    body { width: 400px; }

    p { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0.5em; }

    blockquote {
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        padding-top: 0.5em; padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }

    /* Two workarounds */
    /*
    blockquote { padding-bottom: 1px; }
    blockquote { padding-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid antiquewhite; }
    */

    /* Will not work, due to padding/margin collapsing, as I understand */
    blockquote { padding-bottom: 0; }
</style>

<p>Some text before blockquotes</p>

<blockquote>
<p><strong>1st blockquote</strong></p>
<p>1st paragraph. Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.</p>
<p>2nd paragraph. Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
<p><strong>2nd blockquote</strong></p>
<p>1st paragraph. Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.</p>
<p>2nd paragraph. Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.</p>
</blockquote>

<p>Some text after blockquotes</p>
```

Comment: have you tried removing the margin-bottom of the last paragraph and applying padding-bottom:.5em to the blockquote?

Comment: Did you mean `blockquote p:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }`? Yes, it's another workaround. It's not a good idea, because sometimes it will be another elements (not `p`s) at the bottom of blockquote.

Answer (score 0):

Have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svLzhb1y/2/)

workaround done

```
blockquote p:last-child {
  margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;
}

blockquote {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    padding-top: 0.5em; padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body { width: 400px; }

p { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }

blockquote {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    padding-top: 0.5em; padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

/* Two workarounds */
/*
blockquote { padding-bottom: 1px; }
blockquote { padding-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid antiquewhite; }
*/

/* Will not work, due to padding/margin collapsing, as I understand */

blockquote .content:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
blockquote .title {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
<p class="title"><strong>1st blockquote</strong></p>
<div class="content">
<p>1st paragraph. Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
<p>2nd paragraph. Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.</p>
</div>
</blockquote>
```

you can do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `collpasing margin`s (more info about collapsing margins [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920386/block-formatting-contexts-collapsing-margins-and-floating-containers/39923386#39923386)) and `padding`s are at play here - the easiest thing to do is:

1. Keep the `0.5em` value for `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom` for `blockquote`:

   ```
   blockquote {
     background-color: antiquewhite;
     padding-top: 0.5em;
     padding-bottom: 0.5em;
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0.5em;
   }
   ```
2. Remove the margins from inside the `blockquote` that can collapse - the bottom margin for the last `p` and the top margin for the first `p`

   ```
   blockquote p:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 0;
   }
   blockquote p:first-child {
     margin-top: 0;
   }
   ```

This means the `padding` of `blockquote` will now be responsible for the 0.5em space at the top and bottom within the `blockquote` and `margin-bottom` will act as the separation between them.

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
blockquote {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
blockquote p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
blockquote p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text before blockquotes</p>

<blockquote>
  <p><strong>1st blockquote</strong>
  </p>
  <p>1st paragraph. Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.</p>
  <p>2nd paragraph. Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p><strong>2nd blockquote</strong>
  </p>
  <p>1st paragraph. Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.</p>
  <p>2nd paragraph. Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.</p>
</blockquote>

<p>Some text after blockquotes</p>
```