# html background image cannot display normally

Tags: html, css, background, css-position

I have some problems with the picture display. Below is my code：

```css
.night-sky {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #020107 0%, #311B46 50%, #592C67 60%, #803E7E 75%, #CA759C 90%, #EC9D9D 95%, #C35E4D 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #020107 0%, #311B46 50%, #592C67 60%, #803E7E 75%, #CA759C 90%, #EC9D9D 95%, #C35E4D 100%);
}
.night-sky:before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* http://bg.siteorigin.com/ */
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/424395/night-sky-texture.png");
  opacity: .1;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="night-sky">
    <p>qerqwer</p>
    <p>hahahh</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

If I didn't add the paragraph between the class div `class = "night-sky"` , it just shows nothing. but if i just add the `background-image` in the body it will shows correctly. I don't know what's wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Likely because you have height in percentage, and width not defined. So unless there is an element, there is width/height for night-sky. Hence no bg visible. See a sample fiddle without paragraphs. https://jsfiddle.net/5a2xowwg/

Comment: Link:-http://www.html.am/html-codes/image-codes/background-image-code.cfm

Answer (score 3):

Add `height: 100%` to `html` and that would solve the problem.

Some suggestions:

1. You can see that now there would be some margin at the top - this comes due to **margin collapsing** (you can read more about it in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920386/block-formatting-contexts-collapsing-margins-and-floating-containers/39923386#39923386)). To remove this add a `border` to the `night-sky`
2. Finish it up with:

   ```
   * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   ```

   so that there is no scrollbar on the body - see why `border-box` is important in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129811/add-border-to-div-increase-div-width/39130170#39130170)

Cheers!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
  height: 100%;
}
.night-sky {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #020107 0%, #311B46 50%, #592C67 60%, #803E7E 75%, #CA759C 90%, #EC9D9D 95%, #C35E4D 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #020107 0%, #311B46 50%, #592C67 60%, #803E7E 75%, #CA759C 90%, #EC9D9D 95%, #C35E4D 100%);
}
.night-sky:before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* http://bg.siteorigin.com/ */
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/424395/night-sky-texture.png");
  opacity: .1;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="night-sky">
    <p>qerqwer</p>
    <p>hahahh</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0;}

.night-sky {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #020107 0%, #311B46 50%, #592C67 60%, #803E7E 75%, #CA759C 90%, #EC9D9D 95%, #C35E4D 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #020107 0%, #311B46 50%, #592C67 60%, #803E7E 75%, #CA759C 90%, #EC9D9D 95%, #C35E4D 100%);
}
.night-sky:before {
  width: 100%;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* http://bg.siteorigin.com/ */
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/424395/night-sky-texture.png");
  opacity: .1;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="night-sky">
    <p>qerqwer</p>
    <p>hahahh</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```html
<div style="background-image:url(http://www.html.am/images/image-codes/milford_sound_t.jpg);width:220px;height:140px;">

</div>
```

Comment: If you want you can change height & width as you want.