# IE CSS3 box-shadow with dynamic height

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm trying to make a box shadow for a div with a dynamic height. which works fine with

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#78000a', Direction=180, Strength=15)
```

But only if a specific height is set. But I want a shadow also on an dynamic height. Is this possible? I also tried min-height but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but apparently it often helps if you add

```
zoom:1;
```

to the div's css.

http://jsfiddle.net/wXNRc/2/

(example is IE-only)

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like this is often down to the [`hasLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162625/why-does-internet-explorer-need-the-haslayout-flag) issue in IE.

No guarantees, but try giving the element in question the `zoom: 1` CSS property. This is a IE-only hack to give an element layout.